# Get script content from web page using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get the specific content from `script` tags from a web page.
Here is HTML page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
       <script>
         //some other srcipt code
       </script>
    </head>
<body>
       <script>
         //some other srcipt code
       </script>
    <!-- some other html code -->
<script>
var abc = {"asld":"asdjk","thisone":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/$N.jpg|#1000#M$M#JSuL8|1000#M$M#fW4EC0jcOl8kUY_QBZbOASsF8t0","user_gender":"m"};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get only this value `fW4EC0jcOl8kUY_QBZbOASsF8t0` which is in the last attribute of `thisone` in a script variable `var abc`.
Can I do this with `PHP HTML DOM`. If no then how can I do

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get it using the regex

```
"thisone":".*#(.*)",
```

Assuming, the webpage is http://example.com,

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
preg_match_all("/\"thisone\":\".*#(.*)\",/", $data, $output);
echo $output[1][0]; // prints fW4EC0jcOl8kUY_QBZbOASsF8t0
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is working but this one is very slow any other method which is faster.

Comment: Then how can I get last video in kind of script let asVideoJson = [{"web":"https:\/\/ufac4.net\/","src":"https:\/\/video\/c2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1l\/Ufac4.mp4","type":"video\/mp4"},{"web":"https:\/\/brazil999.net\/","src":"https:\/\/video\/c2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1l\/brazil999.mp4","type":"video\/mp4"},{"web":"https:\/\/hotgraph881.com\/","src":"https:\/\/video\/c2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1lc2FnYW1l\/hotgraph88.mp4","type":"video\/mp4"}];